# Convert unique values of a string column in dataframe into new multiple header with value of 0 or 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column header named Transportation with some values of Car, Bus, Ship or Nan (for missing value). What I intend to do is to extract all the unique value in Transportation (eg. people with id 3 and people with id 6 may have transportation of car) and then put them into new column headers.

Then, if the id 3 's transportation is Car, then the row value is 1 under Car header and 0 under other headers. For Nan, value is 0 under all new generated headers.

Comment: What have you tried? Showing some code is always good to the ones who try to help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way to do it is by using [pandas get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

example:

consider this DataFrame `df`:

```
  Transportation
0            car
1            bus
2          plane
3            NaN
```

if you execute this :

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df,prefix='',prefix_sep='')
print(new_df)
```

you get as output:

```
   bus  car  plane
0    0    1      0
1    1    0      0
2    0    0      1
3    0    0      0
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is called binary encoding of categorical variables:

```
def binary_encode(df, field) 
    df[df['Transportation'] == field][field] = 1
    df[df['Transportation'] != field][field] = 0
```

So for instance, if you call it with field='Car', it will do this:

```
df[df['Transportation'] == 'Car']['Car'] = 1
df[df['Transportation'] != 'Car']['Car'] = 0
```

`df[df['Transportation'] == 'Car']` simply selects all those rows in the dataframe where the value of the `Transportation` column is 'Car'. The rest of it then assigns a value of 1 to a `Car` column for those rows.

At this point, the rows with other values for the `Transportation` column would have NaNs, and we don't want that. So we use a similar technique to assign the value 0 to the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas built in .apply function.

The apply function in this case will take as input a function. This function will be run on each member of the column series and produce a new column. Here is an example which uses lambda functions and inline if else statements to accomplish this concisely:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a sample list which contains the transportation list
transportation_list = ["Car","Bus","Ship",np.nan,"Car","Bus","Ship",np.nan]

# Make a pandas Dataframe with a single column called transportation
df = pd.DataFrame({"Transportation":transportation_list})

# Create additional columns by applying the lambda function to each row in 
# the transportation column and set the value equal to zero or one depending 
# on equivalence to test value.
df['car'] = df["Transportation"].apply(lambda transport_type:1 if "Car" == transport_type else 0)
df['bus'] = df["Transportation"].apply(lambda transport_type:1 if "Bus" == transport_type else 0)
df['ship'] = df["Transportation"].apply(lambda transport_type:1 if "Ship" == transport_type else 0)
```

Giving a result of:

[image: Result of code]

Comment: Thanks for the help!